# How to insert ImageView without an image in Android Studio's designer view?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.1, android-studio-3.1.3

I'm designing an activity using the regular designer, and I want to drag and drop an new `ImageView` into the layout *using designer* (I know how to do it in XML). However, I can't click OK without selecting a source image, which I won't select because I'll be loading a remote image in code:

[image]

Sure, I can pick a random drawable and then remove it after creating, or I can just create it in XML. I was wondering why Android Studio forces me to pick a drawable. Am I missing something, or is it just bad UX?

Answer (score -1):

You can select **color tab** from resource window  then **android** and then select color as **transparent** as simple as that.

Comment: I know I can do that. Just as I've stated in the question, I'm looking for a way *without* doing that. It's of course not as if it's very hard or long process or anything. It's more about "am I missing something" in the interface.